# wp undefined function add_settings_section

Tags: wordpress, function, undefined, call

I'm trying to add sections and fields to a new settings page i WordPress. But I get the response "Call to undefined function add_settings_section()...". Does anybody know why that is?
This is the code in question:
add_settings_section(
        'ac_div',
        'Inställningar',
        'ac_section_text',
        'Anders-counter'
        );

```
add_settings_field(
    'diven',
    'För in mätarställningen här',
    'ac_add_field',
    'Anders-counter',
    'ac_div');
```

Thankful for help.
Anders

Answer (score 7):

`add_settings_field` function located under `wp-admin/includes/template.php`

you can load that file before calling `add_settings_field`, or simply add your code under `admin_init` hook

```
add_action('admin_init', 'your_function');
function your_function(){
    add_settings_field(
        'diven',
        'För in mätarställningen här',
        'ac_add_field',
        'Anders-counter',
        'ac_div'
    );
}
```